# Store data from multiple sources using unified values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I have a situation where data is coming from multiple sources I don't have control over. 
For example:

- Source 1: Location="Austin Texas"
- Source 2: Location="Austin, Tx"
- Source 3: Location="Austin"

In the database I would like all of these to correspond to a single row in my location table for the ease of joins with other tables.

Currently the location table looks like

```
| id | source_id | source_value | value      |  
+----+-----------+--------------+------------+
| ## | 1         | Austin Texas | Austin, Tx |
| ## | 2         | Austin, Tx   | Austin, Tx |
| ## | 3         | Austin       | Austin, Tx |
```

If we then have a table that is like tbl_user_location

```
| user_id | location_id |
```

and a user is in austin, we need to add three rows to the user location table, to make sure all data sources are covered.

While this works, its rather irritating and feels brittle.

Another idea that I've considered is having two tables - a location table and an alias table that points to the "correct" location.
This seems like it would work, but for all tables that get data from multiple data sources it would doubling the number of tables.

The other idea was to have one large alias table like

```
| id | table_id     | source_id | source_value | unified_row_id  |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+
| ## | loc_tbl_id   | 1         | Austin Texas | loc_austin_id   |
| ## | loc_tbl_id   | 2         | Austin, Tx   | loc_austin_id   |
| ## | other_tbl_id | 1         | Some Value   | proper_value_id |
```

Is there a proper way to go about solving this problem? If not, which of the solutions seems the most maintainable, stable, and fast?

Comment: Your solution looks pretty good, except that table_id is something which you usually do not want to maintain: Look into key relations (mysql foreign keys).

Comment: Maintainability, stability and speed are not necessarily complementary... Anyway, I'd probably consider to consolidate the different location values into one, and only translate back into the original, iff actually required in some specific application context. If just the location labelling differs, how does this "cause doubling all tables that get data from multiple data sources"?

Comment: It would double the number of tables because we'd have one table with the "preferred" values, the ones that we want to use, and one table that has the mappings from the input values to the preferred values.